# Why Checkbox is not unchecking in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need to uncheck a checkbox. It is doing everything like alert or removing div, but not unchecking the checkbox. I have used both `attr` and `prop` methods. The checkbox `id` is ok. Even it doesn't show any error in firebug console.

```
$('html').on('click', '#inScopeDiv .remButton', function () {
      var currId = $(this).attr('id');
      var chkBoxId = "#chk"+currId;
      alert(currId);
      alert('#chk'+currId);
      $(chkBoxId).prop("checked", false);
      $(chkBoxId).attr("checked", false);
      $('#div'+ currId).remove();
      $('#inScopeActionDiv' + currId).remove();         
    });
```

**HTML provided ::**

```
<c:forEach items="${data.inScope}" var="inScopeValues">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: snow;">
            <input class="inScope" type="checkbox" id="chk${inScopeValues.key}" name="chk + ${inScopeValues.key}" value="${inScopeValues.value}">
             ${inScopeValues.value}
        </div>  
        </c:forEach>
```

**Button & Checkbox is below ::>**

```
<input class="inScope" type="checkbox" id="chkisc_2" name="chkisc_2" value="In Scope 2">

<button id="chkisc_1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm remButton" title="Remove this item">Remove Item</button>
```

Comment: please you provide your `HTML` as well

Comment: Have you tried this: `$($("#chk" + currId).).attr("checked", false);`

Comment: What does `console.log($(chkBoxId).length)` tell you?

Comment: @Stark I have tried after you provided both with attr and prop. But no luck

Comment: html provided above.

Comment: @nnnnnn Console.log provide `0`. I don't know why. Can you guys please help?

Comment: Where's the HTML for the item being clicked? You've shown server-side code mixed in with the HTML. If you view the page source from your browser what is the actual ID that was generated for that checkbox element? @Stark - No, that'll add the literal space and + characters to the id.

Comment: yes it adds extra + and space

Comment: @nnnnnn I add the button details in my question. It is appended by jquery not present at document ready

Comment: The button you show in the updated question has `id="chkisc_1"`, then in your function you take that and add `#chk` to the beginning of it which would mean you're looking for an element with the selector `"#chkchkisc_1"`. Meanwhile, apparently the checkbox has `id="chkisc_2"`, although it does seem to be created in a loop so perhaps there is also a `_1` - but that would mean you have more than one element with the same id, which is invalid html.

Comment: it's ok now. I have removed the `chk` after `#`. But still no result.

Comment: @nnnnnn you were right. I had the same id with button with the class remButton. Thanks man. I change the button id and it works fine. please put it as answer so that i can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button you show in the updated question has `id="chkisc_1"`, then in your function you take that and add `#chk` to the beginning of it which would mean you're looking for an element with the selector `"#chkchkisc_1"`. Meanwhile, apparently the checkbox has `id="chkisc_2"`, although it does seem to be created in a loop so perhaps there is also a `_1` (though that would mean you have more than one element with the same id, which is invalid html).

Change the button to have `id="isc_1"`, then when your JS adds `#chk` it will be looking for `#chkisc_1`:

```js
$('html').on('click', '#inScopeDiv .remButton', function () {
    var currId = $(this).attr('id');
    var chkBoxId = "#chk"+currId;
    $(chkBoxId).prop("checked", false);
    $('#div'+ currId).remove();
    $('#inScopeActionDiv' + currId).remove();         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inScopeDiv">

<input class="inScope" type="checkbox" id="chkisc_1" name="chkisc_1" value="In Scope 1" checked>
<button id="isc_1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm remButton" title="Remove this item">Remove Item</button>

<input class="inScope" type="checkbox" id="chkisc_2" name="chkisc_2" value="In Scope 2" checked>
<button id="isc_2" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm remButton" title="Remove this item">Remove Item</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I had the same id with button with the class remButton. Thanks man. I change the button id and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `prop()` and `removeAttr()` to achieve this.. Hope it helps!

```js
var cb = $("#checkbox")

$('#button1').click(function() {
  cb.prop("checked", true)
})

$('#button2').click(function() {
  cb.removeAttr('checked')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />This is a checkbox
<br />
<br />
<button id="button1">Check checkbox</button>
<br />
<br />
<button id="button2">Uncheck checkbox</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelector("input");

checkbox.addEventListener("click",function(){
  console.log("Sorry ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)");
  this.checked = false;
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```